# commiting to GitHub on IntelliJ-idea

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, commit, git-commit

When I try to commit, the intellij show this error message:
[image]

That is only solved when I change the name of the folders in the local directory writing wrong like in pathspec `Gere^encia`, then the intellij-idea does the commit without error, but the commit doesn't go to the remote directory. The problem seems to be with the brazilian portuguese language, or with something in the encoding, but I tried everything, search on the web and nothing solved my problem.

If someone could give a little help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `git add` and `git commit` work from command line?
Looks related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164612